# Gherkin - real or representative scenarios?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Lets say that my app works with some books with real titles "The Old Man and the Sea", "War and Peace", etc., when creating scenarios, should I use real title like:

```
Given I have a book "War and Peace" persisted
When ...
```

or should I do something like:

```
Given I have a book "Book1" persisted
When ...
```

Option 2 is more generic, but artificial example. And If I use first option, person who is reading the test has to have domain knowledge, and he will also have some presumptions about the scenario as soon as he reads the title of the book.

Also, is there some simpler way for me to create data table without repeating data (in this case page where I have always to repeat 1,1,2,2,2,2...)? example:

```
When we receive book with following content:
    | Page  | Line  | Text  |
    | 1     | 1     | a     |
    | 1     | 2     | b     |
    | 2     | 1     | a     |
    | 2     | 2     | b     |
```

is this standard way to do it:

```
When we receive a book
And page 1 has content
   | Line  | Text  |
   | 1     | a     |
   | 2     | b     |
And page 2 has content
   | Line  | Text  |
   | 1     | a     |
   | 2     | b     |
```

Comment: What is the business concern or rule that you are testing? This sounds mostly like you are writing a test of the persistence layer rather then describing the applications behavior. You don't need to use Gherkin for that.

Comment: The rule was just that when I receive book from somebody (bookDTO) that it is persisted in DB. You mean that this kind of tests should not go in cucumber? Only functional tests like "given book has 10 pages, when I remove 1 page book will have 9 pages left"? I mean, cannot you treat this also as a functional test - like receiving book from somebody, I have somehow to save it.

Comment: No. The purpose of Cucumber is to support BDD. And generally that means you write your scenarios in business terms. And the business does not use a language that contains concepts like dtos, persistence or anything of the sort. Take a few steps back, what does your application actually do?

https://cucumber.io/docs/bdd/

Comment: So how would you then write use case for receiving book from somebody and saving it to  - lets call it library (let's also say I want to have online library app - basically it takes a DTO and stores it to DB).? Would you just write unit tests for this case?

Comment: Something like a unit test or an integration test. Preferably only the API - no peeking in the database.  Depends a bit on everything else that surrounds the the system. A rule to test with BDD would be something along the lines of "Books are overdue after 30 days. When a book is overdue no new books  can lend to that account".

Comment: I really do not see that big difference between those 2 use-cases. Both are functional requirements - 1st one - received book needs to be saved/persisted, and 2nd one - book cannot be lend more than 30 days. I cannot find some strict rules to follow here, and I guess it all depends who is implementing the system. On the other hand, my question was related to the names used in scenarios. Lets say you can have some cars - "BMW", "Mercedes", "Toyota"... and scenario When "BMW" is washed. Instead of BMW I can use any car manufacturer. But then someone could ask - why BMW why not Toyota.

Comment: I could repeat this scenario for all manufacturers, but it is repeating same code over and over, just changing manufacturers. On the other hand if I say When "CarManufacturer" is washed... - I'm using artificial manufacturer named "CarManufacturer" to represent all possible manufacturers here.

Comment: You can't see the problem because you are inventing novel domain language as we speak. BookDTOs, CarManufacturer, persistence.This is not the language your business uses. Go talk to them, capture that language.

Comment: And yes, people are supposed to ask you what is so special about Toyota. Is Toyota different from the others or is there a generic brand? Or is it a generic manufacturer? Or a company? And is it really generic or does the system treat each one slightly different in places? This discussion is the whole point. And if you have this discussion the right answer usually just falls out.

Comment: Well, they do not mention DTOs. CarManufacturer they would say When any car is washed... But for this use case I need to have some manufacturer - so I could manually in the code backend init it to whatever (since it is mandatory). And they do mention DB's I guess today everyone knows about DBs...

Answer (score 0):

First of all start with the name of the scenario, this name should be meaningful and should be like a summary about what is about the test.

Once you have the name then the other steps should describe a business flow that of course should contain domain language, because for example if i don't know nothing about healthcare, banking etc then why would I understand a test about a specific domain subject?, the scenarios are for a specific group of people (the ones that are working in the specific domain).

One of the BDD role is to help in understanding better the specifications and the application on all levels (technical to non-technical, but on the same business domain), to improve communication.

Now for your specific issue.
`Given I have a book "War and Peace" persisted` does not offer to much info since the title of the book says nothing about the test data; is a new book that just was added/created?, is a type of book technical/poetry or just some book?

What was useful for me is use a name for the the data that says something about the data used in the test.
If you don't have different types of books you can use any name, else a more complete name would be more useful.

As for the table, that represents a data set and you need to tell what to check and where; depending by case you could group some checks, if you can read all data at once or not, or if you need to specify the texts/pages.

One option would be to hide the data set and say something like:

```
Given I have a book "War and Peace" persisted
Then the book contains the expected content for "War and Peace"
```

- in the first step "War and Peace" - gets/creates a specific book that is identified by this title
- in the second step "War and Peace" - identifies a set of data for the expected result using the same name since is the expected for that specific data set, this set of data can be list/array/map ... depending of what programming language you are using.

Don't think to much to the details, just define the scenario in human readable language using outside-in approach, then see if you can refine it and after start the implementation.

> Always use a description for the feature and a meaningful title for each scenario

Comment: So you are saying that I do not have to have explicit "Then" definition in gherkin? I mean if I use this: "Then the book contains the expected...", I would probably have to have a lot of code in the test implementation that would not be visible in gherkin definition. It just seems that you could then always use "Then It Magically Works", and nobody (reading only gherkin spec) knows what it is supposed to do.

Comment: You do, you have to follow the guide rules, the validation step from my example is `the book contains the expected content for "War and Peace"`, but the details in the scenario needs to bring value and also adding to much details can damage, you need to find the right balance and the right amount of details so that you can have reusable steps but  also meaningful. Given-When-Then just give context for preconditions, actions, results and helps you to set clear delimitation for these.